# Laravel files refuse to update

Tags: laravel

I've run across an error that I have no idea what to do with.

Thing is I have a view file for an delete confirmation page which was working, and I tried adding some code which resulted in a regular error. Now that I've tried to remove the changes I did, I only get an error saying that I have a class that is not found (which I can only assume is referring to the eloquent model, which I do have, and was working no more than 5 minutes ago).

HOWEVER: It "works" for some of the output which I would want to detelete. Now whenever I do some changes in the view files, a refresh does not reflect these changes, at all.

I was just wondering if anyone has ran into similar problems as my google search did not find anything that helped.

(Running wamp server)

Comment: i wonder how this __poor__ question got 2 upvotes within 60 seconds....

Comment: It's hard to pin down the specific problem based on your description, but try removing your cached views (in `app/storage/`) and see if that helps. If it does, it suggests your filesystem is somehow caching modified times or something and so Laravel doesn't know to regenerate a blade template.

Comment: @alexrussell Thanks, that seemed to fix it.

Comment: FYI, running `php artisan cache:clear` is probably the correct way rather than manually deleting cached data.

Answer (score 0):

Try running php artisan clear-compiled